# How to display date and time in input datetime-local

Tags: php, html, mysql, datetime

I have created a table with field date_time and its data type is **datetime**.

I am fetching records from this table using PHP, and I want to show this date and time in HTML page.

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="date"/>
```

I am setting its value attribute, but its not showing the date, Is there any conversion I need to perform to show this date time in input of HTML?

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: Please show us your code so we can see how you fetch records from db.

Comment: What is the value that you are setting for the input?

Comment: Date time needs to be in this format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm` e.g. `2017-06-01T08:30` for datetime-local control

Comment: @Strawberry, fetching date time from Mysql, so it must come in the format of MySQL date time, so I have mention the mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the mysql date value to the default format of datetime-local of HTML,
Use this function for conversion.

```
date ('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($Yordatevalue));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
<?php
    $date = '2020-05-12T08:30'; // Or how you fetch the records?
?>

<input type="datetime-local" name="date" value="<?php echo $date;?>"/>
```